# Архитектура взаимодействия TCP-сервера и GUI через очередь сообщений

Tags: архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Подскажите, как грамотно организовать архитектуру взаимодействие TCP-сервера, реализованного внутри приложения, и интерфейса, представленного ввиде окна с набором виджетов.

Логика работы приложения:
Создается главное окно приложения
Создается дополнительный поток
Внутри созданного потока запускается сервер, принимающий сообщения от клиентов
Сервер должен записывать принятые от клиентов сообщения в очередь сообщений для главного окна, которое, в свою очередь по таймеру забирает сообщения из очереди и отображает их на экране.

Вопрос в том, где создавать очередь. Первый вариант, простой и понятный: сделать ее глобально видимой для сервера и главного окна. Но считается, что использования глобальных переменных следует избегать, вроде не грамотный код и т.д. и т.п.

Если создать очередь в главном окне, то сложно передавать ссылку на очередь в сервер. Приходится передавать ссылку в объект создаваемого потока, потом в конструктор сервера, а в сервере для каждого клиента создаются объекты-сессии и надо передавать еще в эти объекты-сессии ссылку на очередь, чтобы можно было писать в эту очередь. Очень муторно....
Привожу схему взаимодействия классов через глобальную очередь и очередь, создаваемую в классе главного окна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]